# Why I am getting Bufferholder error in Databricks even my cluster size is of 8GB

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks

Hey I am getting this error when I run my pyspark python code in databricks.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder by size 8 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483632
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error and how I can resolve it. This error is getting when I am dividing the huge json file in two parts.

Here is the python code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col
import itertools

# Read the JSON file from Databricks storage
df_json = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("/mnt/BigData_JSONFiles/2022-10_040_05C0_in-network-rates_2_of_2.json")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "false")

df_network=df_json.select(df_json.columns[1:])
df_version=df_json.select(df_json.columns[:1])

df_network.write.format("json").save("/mnt/BigData_JSONFiles/2022-10_040_05C0_in-network-rates_2_of_2_detail.json")
df_version.write.format("json").save("/mnt/BigData_JSONFiles/2022-10_040_05C0_in-network-rates_2_of_2_header.json")
display(df_network)
display(df_version)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: what's the size of your json file, and the size of your DBX cluster?

Comment: 2GB JSON file and 8GB Cluster

Answer (score 0):

It is because one of your column size exceeds the 2GB limit - details in this article below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/sql/cannot-grow-bufferholder-exceeds-size